# Alert After All Elements Have Loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a quiz, and if you get 100%, when you load the last page, it will alert "You got 100%!". Although, it loads in before the background loads in. This is my code:

```js
var chanceoflive1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive1"));
    var chanceoflive2 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive2"));
    var chanceoflive3 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive3"));
    var chanceoflive4 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive4"));
    var chanceoflive7 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive7"));

    var chanceoflivefinal = (chanceoflive1||0) + (chanceoflive2||0) + (chanceoflive3||0) + (chanceoflive4||0) + (chanceoflive7||0);
    var chanceoflivepercent = chanceoflivefinal * 4;
   

function startup(){
        if (chanceoflivefinal == 25) {
            alert("You Got 100%!");
        }
    }
```

```html
<body onload="startup">
<center>
    <h2 class="text">Final Results</h2>

    <p id="print" class="text"></p>
    <p id="print2" class="text"></p>

    <img src="qrcode.jpg" height="300" length="300">

    <br>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="index.html">
    <button align=center onclick="handleClick()" id="button">
      <canvas width="200" height="50" id="canvas" align=center></canvas>
      <span class="text" id="submit">Retry</span>
    </button>
        </a>
    </div>
    </center>
  </body>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to put `()` after a function to call it, `onload="startup()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do something like this within a `script` tag:

```
(function(){ // on document load
    alert("Ready!"); // alert "ready"
})();
```

Oh, and as **@Barmar** said, to call that `function`, you need to change `startup` to `startup()`

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I forgot to put the `()` after the function. I feel like a noob.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing `();`  like this `onload="startup();"`.

Perhaps you can also use

```
document.onload = startup();
```

or even

```
window.onload = startup();
```